# NSFileManager: move file to a NTFS hard disk

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion, ntfs, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to copy some files from local HD (journaled, of course) to a USB hard disk, partitioned with NTFS.

I'm simply using

```
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:src toPath:dest error:&err]
```

which works fine.

However, for some files (I didn't understand the relation between these files), when I try to delete them from the NTFS drive I get a Finder error

> The operation could not be completed.
>   An unexpected error occurred (error code -50).

I tried to search the web, I read it may be a problem of illegal characters in the name `? / " | > *`, but none of those characters is in the name of the files that give me the error (I didn't check for *every* file that gives me that error, also because I have hundreds of files, but one that gives that error every time is `asdf.txt`, thus I think it's not related to file names...).

Besides (I don't know if it's related or not), when the popup with the error appears I have, as you know, two choices. The file gets deleted even if I cancel the operation.

Any suggestion on how I can solve? (except, of course, not using a NTFS drive)
I'm using MacOSX 10.7.2 and Xcode 4.2.1.

Comment: How is that NTFS disk mounted to the system?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon what do you mean? It's a USB drive...

Comment: I mean NTFS volumes are not natively supporting read/write operations on MacOS X, right?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Oh yes, sorry, I use `Paragon NTFS for MacOSX`, v9.0.1